# Remove W3 Total Cache minified files on custom page outside of WordPress

Tags: multisite, loop, plugin-w3-total-cache, outside-wordpress

I have [created a page](http://www.iwcollege.ac.uk/facebookapps/iwcollege/courses.php) outside my WP network install ([following this info from css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/run-a-loop-outside-of-wordpress/))

The output of which is used for a Facebook business page tab as a Facebook app.

It is working just fine, however I use W3 Total Cache on the site and noticed the output contains redundant (in this instance) minified JS files, is there a way to stop The W3 Total Cache plugin from hooking in & including these files?

The output is minified, which is a good thing so ideally i'd like to keep the minified output without the js files as they are not required.

Any help, tips or links appreciated, thanks in advance,

Aaron :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add DONOTMINIFY define statement to this page to disable it or switch to manual minify mode where this template has no settings.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to kleep the minified CSS that W3 give, but not the JS?

To do this add this where you `wp_head` runs.

```
<?php
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);
wp_head();
```

This should remove all JS wich W3 prints.
It will remove ALL JS which is registered with [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://wordpress.org/search/wp_enqueue_script)

*not tested